# How do I make these buttons different styles?

Tags: html, css

So I am new to HTML & CSS. I am trying to make the top button (Get It Now) different from the button on the bottom (Sign Up Now). I put in different classes and tried id's but it doesn't seem to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firexfox */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* IE */
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("../images/header_bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #033048;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
  background: #f9e42e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.benefits {
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #f0efef;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 120px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 128px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #033048;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #f9e42e;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

p {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #606161;
  line-height: 38px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #606161;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.benefits p {
  width: 640px;
}

.benefits ul {
  width: 640px;
}

.quote {
  background-image: url("../images/testimonial_bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 300px 60px 300px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.quote p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}

#attribution {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 6px;
}

.bar {
  background-color: #f9e42e;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
  background: #033048;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #121212;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.footer a {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Relaxr</h1>
  <h2>Get piece of mind with a single tap</h2>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing">Get it Now</a>
  <!-- I just selected a random link that was "relaxing" for now-->
</div>
<div class="benefits">
  <h3>Benefits</h3>
  <p>The perfect personal assistant. Relaxr does your job for you so you can enjoy life as it is meant to be.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>• Schedule meetings for you</li>
    <li>• Excel automation to complete work for you</li>
    <li>• Responds to emails on your behalf</li>
    <li>• Does all your work for you with our revolutionary AI technology</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  <p>“Relaxr changed my life. I’ve been able to travel the world, spend limited time working and my boss keeps thanking me for crushing work.”</p>
  <p id="attribution">- Amanda, Intuit</p>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing">Sign Up Now!</a>
  <!-- I just selected a random link that was "relaxing" for now-->
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h4>Relaxr</h4>
  <br />
  <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="social"> <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Icon"></a>
  <a href="https://facebook.com/" class="social"> <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Icon"></a>
  <br />
  <p>Copyright 2015. Relaxr.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w5mrzxny/

Comment: The buttons have different styles already and is working just fine. Please elaborate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a class like this

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing" class="TopButton">Get it Now</a>
```

And then add css for the class

```
.TopButton {
  background-color:lightgray;
  border:solid;
  padding:3px;
}
```

Comment: awesome! thank you. that works!

Answer (score 2):

IDs and classes should work...
In case you just made a simple mistake, remember that IDs are called with #, like #foo, and classes with periods(.), like .bar.  Other than that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should add classes to your buttons directly. That would be much more maintainable than using all those complex selectors.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing">Get it Now</a>
    <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing">Sign Up Now!</a>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback so far. As a newbie I really appreciate it! As far as adding classes to my buttons go, I tried that and it didn't work. Could the issue be the way I was writing it in the Css? Would I write the above example as " .btn btn-primary a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active " ? Or do I need to call out the div class too?

Comment: nevermind. i played with it and got it to work based on your response and user5504817's. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The buttons do have different styles.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firexfox */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* IE */
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #033048;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
  background: #f9e42e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.bar {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bar a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing">Get it Now</a>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.blissworld.com/spa-landing">Sign Up Now!</a>
</div>
```

However, this is not doing what you think it is:

```
.header a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    color: #033048;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
    background: #f9e42e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

it should be:

```
.header a:link, 
.header a:visited, 
.header a:hover, 
.header a:active {
    color: #033048;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
    background: #f9e42e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the same applies to the `bar` link styles.

```
bar a:link,
.bar a:link,
.bar a:visited,
.bar a:hover,
.bar a:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 11px 56px 11px 56px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```